# One liner to rearrange fields for a matching item

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk, sed

What's a smart and clean/concise way to rearrange fields that match a criterion? For my purposes, the records could be blocks separated by blank lines, e.g.:

```
apple
banana
12345
carrot

donut
98765
eggplant
```

or tab delimited, e.g.,

```
apple   banana   12345   carrot
donut   98765   eggplant
```

In either case, assume I am looking for the pattern `/[0-9]{5}/`. If matched, I want to move it to the first record. That would yield the following:

```
12345
apple
banana
carrot

98765
donut
eggplant
```

or tab delimited, e.g.,

```
12345   apple   banana   carrot
98765   donut   eggplant
```

There's no need to support both formats. They are interchangeable for me.

One-liner preferred.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a "write my code for me" site. You have to put forth some effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Jim, I understand why it could seem that way, but the challenge here is doing it in one line. I can think of many ways to do this with small scripts, but I can't figure out how to do it with a few pipes or characters. Maybe I should have been clearer about the importance of a one-liner. I just didn't say it because a super-short script can typically be converted to a one-liner.

Comment: `awk '/^[0-9]+$/ {printf $0"\t"; next}{if ($0 ~ /^$/) {print block; block=""} else {block=block$0"\t"}} END{print block}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you first example, a one liner that would work would be:

```
perl -00 -pe "s/\A(.*?)^(\d{5}\n)/$2$1/sm" j1.txt
```

To run on a unix system, replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Update: made 2 changes to the regular expression.

Comment: Hi Chris. That's really nice, and thanks for the heads up about the single quotes. That's elegant with the /sm. I am not good with multiline regex. And I didn't know about -00 to use blank lines as a record separator.

Comment: Also, Chris, can you take a look at my related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051094/how-to-sort-fields-in-a-record?noredirect=1#comment59750407_36051094  (I don't know why I am getting flamed with the down votes, btw. I thought these were both interesting little problems.)  Does the -00 trick help sort within blocks of text?

Comment: @MichaelDouma: You are getting downvotes because you appear to have made no effort at all to solve t0his problem for yourself. When you have written some code but cannot get it to work no matter what you try, that is the time to post it on Stack Overflow and ask for help with making it work. People generally take a dim view of questions where your approach to problem solving is just to dump your work here without having added to it at all

Comment: @Borodin Thanks. I think you are right. I didn't want to be winy, but I had worked several hours on the puzzle of trying to condense a few lines of code into one. I didn't know the tricks that the answerer (Chris) suggested. Next time, I will give more back story so it doesn't sound like a "help me do my job" thing.

Comment: No, don't give more back story.  Just show the best you _did_ come up with in your question.

Comment: @MichaelDouma: Why are you so set on a one-liner anyway? Put your code into a script file; that way it should be more readable and you can still run it with one line of bash

Comment: Portability. And also curiosity/interest.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'function out() {if (x) {print x; x="";}}
  NF==0 {out(); print; next}
  /^[0-9]{5}$/ {print; out(); next}
  {x=x?(x RS $0):$0}
  END {out()}'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the all on one line version, try (untested):

```
perl -pi -wle's/^(.*?) ([0-9]{5}(?![^ ]))(.*)/$2 $1$3/'
```

Assuming you want only 5 digits to be moved, not something *containing* 5 digits.